# Patching dependent npm package

Tags: npm, webpack

I've found a bug in [jslib-html5-camera-photo](https://github.com/MABelanger/jslib-html5-camera-photo), that prohibits the library from properly handling the scenario where camera access is blocked.

Although the report came for a different reason, there seems to be a [valid patch](https://github.com/MABelanger/jslib-html5-camera-photo/issues/9) out there.

My use case is by way of the react-html5-camera-photo, which provides an error handler. The error handler is never invoked, because of the underlying issue in jslib-html5-camera-photo.

I've forked [jslib-html5-camera-photo](https://github.com/quickshiftin/jslib-html5-camera-photo/tree/stable) (which compiles). I've also forked [react-html5-camera-photo](https://github.com/quickshiftin/react-html5-camera-photo) changing only the jslib-html5-camera-photo dependency:

```
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index d1dca32..b60036e 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -35,7 +35,7 @@
   "homepage": "https://mabelanger.github.io/react-html5-camera-photo/",
   "license": "MIT",
   "dependencies": {
-    "jslib-html5-camera-photo": "3.0.2-beta.0"
+    "jslib-html5-camera-photo": "github:quickshiftin/jslib-html5-camera-photo#stable"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
```

The problem now is react-html5-camera-photo fails to build

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/jslib-html5-camera-photo/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| console.log(document.getElementById('root'));
| ReactDOM.render(<AppReact />, document.getElementById('root'));
|
```

I'm unsure why it's looking at `index.js`, as the package.json file of jslib-html5-camera-photo has these critical lines

```
"main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "npm run buildNpm",
```

It seems like `npm run buildNpm` is not getting called however... Any idea what I'm missing to get this setup working? Feels like there is some npm detail I'm missing, but unsure what it is.

Comment: It looks like the build uses webpack, I'm trying to dig into it now; I've added the webpack tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

Once I realized that the build was powered by webpack, I started googling around and found this [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/) regarding Module Resolution.

I also inspected *package.json* in the "stable" version of *jslib-html5-camera-photo* (the one inside of *node_modules/jslib-html5-camera-photo*. What I ultimately realized is the version of the packages in npm have a *build* directory and do not have a *src* directory.

Therefore, by pushing *build* directories on both my forked projects I got the fork of *react-html5-camera-photo* to build, and then was able to successfully include that in my project proper.

What's more - the patch I needed for *jslib-html5-camera-photo* that precipitated this whole thing works as advertised, and now the error handler in *react-html5-camera-photo* is being invoked!